# Nextgen TinyMce image description field doesn't format HTML probably when outputing on website

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, nextgen-gallery

I installed http://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-tinymce-description

I input the following test content in NextGen Image Description:

> "test content [html link](http://www.example.com/)"

On the webpage it output displays

```
"test content <a href="http://www.example.com">html link</a>"
```

The code for outputting the description is

```
<?php echo $image->description ?>
```

How do make it outputting correctly like what has been input in the Image Description with tinyMCE installed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Eureka!
I found the fixed.
    
    <?php echo html_entity_decode($image->description); ?>

Comment: Consider creating an answer out of this, so other will see that the problem has been solved.